# Is it possible to determine whether the current browser tab has history?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on a view, which on submit directs the user's browser back to the previous page using `window.history.go(-1);`. This is necessary for us to maintain session data to display the previous view correctly.

My question is, is it possible for us to determine whether there is any browser history using jQuery so that if there is none we can instead redirect the user with

```
window.location = "/Transaction/Index";
```

to the correct page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history):

> HTML5 introduced the `history.pushState()` and `history.replaceState()`
>   methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries,
>   respectively. These methods work in conjunction with the
>   `window.onpopstate` event.
>
> Using `history.pushState()` changes the referrer that gets used in the
>   HTTP header for `XMLHttpRequest` objects created after you change the
>   state. The referrer will be the URL of the document whose window is
>   `this` at the time of creation of the `XMLHttpRequest` object.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
> history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
> ```